# Encrypting data before Saas-solution

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

The compliance department is asking me for recommendations on encrypting data before Saas-solutions. Meaning that the Saas-solution should not be able to see the data when stored and processed.

Reading about Fully Homomorphic Encryption seems like it would solve the issue, but i can't seem to really find out how widespread it is, and if there are any products providing it. As far as i can read from it, it is only is relevant for Saas solutions during very simple calculations on the data.

In my mind it seems like a difficult (impossible?) issue.

Has any of you had this problem? What kind of documentation, products, whitepapers, webinars is available on this topic?

Thanks in advance!

(All of this is in regards to the GDPR's requirement for processing data in unsafe third countries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the type of analysis you want to do and how frequently you want to do it. FHE might be an option. Companies such as Zama and Duality are developing products in this area. But keep in mind it's very much still an active research area.

The reseouces in this field is vast. Maybe an easier start is to take a look at some of the blog posts from these two companies https://www.zama.ai/blog and https://dualitytech.com/blog/. There are topics that range from doing machine learning, how to select the FHE library to technical description of FHE schemes.

On the other hand, if the regulatory situation allows you to store data on independent data centers, then you may be able to use secure multiparty computation. This is typically much more efficient than FHE. The basic idea is to split your data into two or more parts such that each individual part does not reveal any information about the original data. These data centers each store one part of the data and can run a protocol to compute what you want. Or a user can download the pieces it wants and do the computation by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

In regards to FHE and other technologies supporting processing on encrypted data: Im guessing that the Saas-solution would need to support this? We cant just send (homomorphic) encrypted data to the Saas-solution and count on their ability to process it, right?

Im asking because i need to come with a realistic judgement to our compliance team. If the Saas-providers need to support it, then we need to have it as a requirement for Saas-solutions, which might not be realistic since not many Saas-solutions have the capability (yet?).

Comment: Indeed, I'm not aware of any SaaS offering that supports FHE. The technology is not mature enough for that.